# The code is correct yet it needs try-catch.. why is that?

Tags: try-catch

I am very new to programming and I saw this code that runs perfect with try/catch.

I thought then try/catch is not necessary, as all I know that it just for checking errors and to change the message of the compile when in error.

But when I removed it the code renders many errors and refuse to compile.  So what is try/catch is really doing here? because

> The code:
>
> import java.io.FileWriter;
>
> public class html {
>
> ```
> public static void main(String[] args) {
>
>     try{    
>        FileWriter fw=new FileWriter("E:\\rrr.html");    
>        fw.write("Welcome to javaTpoint.");    
>        fw.close();    
>       }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}    
>       System.out.println("Success...");    
>  }
> ```

Comment: Google for "exception handling"

Comment: Thank you, I am trying to do. But do you mean this sort of coding must (or may) render some errors in Java so that we need try/catch?  Such as in ClassNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException, RemoteException, etc.? do I get it right here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The FileWriter class always throws an exception i.e, 'IOException',
>   Hence, whenever you use it IOException needs to be handled, so the
>   try-catch block is mandatory while using FileWriter.

**What is an IOException?**

An IOException is any unexpected problem the JVM encounters while attempting to run a program. Possible problems that it may encounter are:

- attempting to read from a file that does not exist
- attempting to write to a file that has an invalid name (a slash or a question mark in the title should do it)
- attempting to read the next token in a file when there are no more tokens.

When an IOException is thrown, it means that whatever is throwing the exception (perhaps a try{}-catch block that reads data from a file) can throw an IOException, for example if the file is not found, corrupted, etc, or when the file is otherwise unable to be read, or any other of a list of issues that can occur with the IO package and it's extensions.